# Does nginx use first server context as a default even when server_name directive doesn't match?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain `example.com`

I wanted to have 2 subdomains: `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` pointing to directories `/var/www/a` and `/var/www/b`  respectively.

So I'm using this nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name a.example.com;
  root /var/www/a;
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}

server {
  server_name b.example.com;
  root /var/www/b;
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

And it works as expected.

**But** when I open up **`c.example.com`** it renders **`/var/www/a/index.html`**

Note that I haven't specified any rule for `c.example.com`.

So why does it behave as if it were matching `a.example.com`?

Does nginx treats the first rule as the default one when nothing else matches? -- Even when the `server_name` directive in that rule doesn't really match the URL?

Comment: Yes. See docs on listen directive

Comment: Also this worth reading http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks! Quite a surprising behavior to be honest. But that answers my question, so if you'd like to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: As @AlexeyTen mentions it will use the first one, or you can add `default_server` option to the listen directive to choose a default option when the hostname does not match the list of available servers instead of relying in the order.

Comment: It's look like that you have some `*.example.com CNAME example.com` record for `example.com` zone in the DNS that associate all undefined (and possibly unwanted) subdomains with the host where your `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` subdomains resides. That is useful behaviour but you have to handle it with separate `nginx` server section with `default` qualificator that inform user about wrong server name.